# mongodb: updating a document or replacing the existing one, what is faster

Tags: mongodb-query, vert.x, mongodb-java

I have a document hierarchy in one collection that for some documents may be rather deep. For example a document may contain an array of objects which themselves can contain other objects and possibly arrays. These documents actually represent objects that I hold in RAM : they are Vertx verticles representing connected users. APIs interact with these in memory representations for, for example, change the value of a field, or add a new one, or retrieve another one. When data is changed in RAM, it needs to be persisted.

Here, I have two alternatives:

1. as I have the full object in memory, including its `_id`, the first option would be to replace the whole document on disk by the object in RAM. This would also allow to do persistence only from time to time, say after five or ten data changes or creations, which will also speedup the process
2. or, to  persist only that very part that had changed, which might be tricky if the data to be updated lies somewhere deeply in the structure

The easiest solution is clearly the first one, but I was wondering if it would be the fastest one, as it writes full blocks of data even for small changes ?

**Update**: To make things clearer, here is an extract of such a document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc000df5afdb9451e0fe762"),
    "email" : {
        "not_validated" : [ ],
        "validated" : [
            {
                "email" : "user2@yopmail.com",
                "ts" : NumberLong("1556087007701")
            }
        ],
        "default" : "user2@yopmail.com"
    },
    "msisdn" : {
        "not_validated" : [ ],
        "validated" : [ ]
    },  
    "last_connection_ts" : NumberLong("1556087007701"),
    .....
}
```

`email` object has two arrays that hold all *validated* and *not yet validated* (not yet confirmed by the user) emails. Sometimes, a first level element as `last_connection_ts` will be changed, but sometimes, when a not validated email becomes validated, it needs to be removed from `not_validated`  array and added into `not_validated` array.

Comment: I would expect an update to be faster, unless it ends up changing the size of the document. But you need to run a test using your own data and update patterns.

Comment: I agree with @JohnnyHK test in your infrastructure and expected load. How many documents do you have to keep in memory? 1MB? 10MB?1GB? 100GB?

Comment: This might be very dependent on where your DB is located relative to the server. If your DB is in the same location (rack or data center) it might be trivial to update the whole document, but if not then network bandwidth & response time might be a considerable bottleneck.